# Language settings - translate menu items

Tags: typo3, typoscript

can someone please tell me what typoscript setting ist responsible to hide menu items when there is no translation for the current language? I thought it was

```
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

but that does not work. Menu items which are not translated are displayed as well.

TYPO3 6.2

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Ist that still the case in 8.7?

Comment: Can't check right now, I don't have a multilanguage site running on 8.7 right now to do some tests.

Answer (score 0):

Like shown in this screenshot: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/_images/LocalizationOverviewHideIfNoTranslation.png
I will have to check the "Hide page if no translation for current language exists" checkbox for every page. Maybe I will do this by manipulating the databse directly (phpmyadmin).

It would be good to also set the default for new pages. This can be done by this page TSconfig:

```
TCAdefaults.pages.l18n_cfg = 2
```